# MFMailComposeViewController in UIActivityViewController has default blue tint colour

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposer

I am presenting activity controller as below:

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [SettingsProvider.shareUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also,  I have set global tint color for the navigation bar, window tint color using appearance property.

When I click application such as message app, the controller takes app tint color for bar buttons except for `MFMailViewController`.
Is there any way to change tint colour of presented applications of `UIActivityController`.

Changing `BarButton` appearance would create a problem for my app. Any other solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution but don't know if this is right way.

Writing an extension to `MFMailComposeViewController` saved me.

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

`MFMailComposeViewController` presented through Activity controller will correspond to extension I have written. In this way, `MFMailComposeViewController` will respond to overridden **`viewDidLoad()`** method.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code for changing bar button color I think it will help you.

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x034517)
```

**OR**

please use this code I have use this code in objective c.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];        
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setToRecipients:@[@"abc@def.com"]];

[mailViewController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have already set this in appDelegate. I have a problem with presented MFMailComposeViewController of UIActivityViewController.

Comment: I have tried this but not working.facing same issue.

Comment: I have Update my Code please refer. @cgeek

Comment: I am presenting UIActivityViewController through which I get to open several applications such as mail or message apps. I don't have direct access to mail. Your code is used to present mail view controller.

Comment: I have found solution. I have posted in answers section.